# hyperlinking to a webdav folder

Tags: internet-explorer, webdav

Is it possible to hyperlink to a WebDAV folder?

That is, can we embed a link in a webapp that opens a url within the same webapp as WebDAV folder, preferably within the same HTTP session? It only needs to work for Internet Explorer.

So far, I have found RFC 4709, which appears to be not implemented by Internet Explorer 8. (Correct?)

I have also tried `file://127.0.0.1:8080/mywebapp/webdav` (IE 8 says it cannot find the directory, even though `http://127.0.0.1:8080/mywebapp/webdav` can be opened with IE 7's open dialog using "Open as Web Folder".)

Answer (score 1):

RFC 4709 contains a sample implementation for IE. Just run the script in [Appendix B.1](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4709.html#rfc.section.B.1).

Comment: Wow, from the author himself! I can not install anything on the client, but I was able to reuse the JavaScript code. (It's ok for us to navigate using JavaScript rather than a hyperlink). However, the script doesn't appear to work in IE 8 (It says: "Unexpected status: FAILED"). Of course, in true Microsoft fashion, IE doesn't say why navigation failed.